# Do we need to put namenode in safe mode before restarting the job tracker?

Tags: hadoop, namenode

I have a Hadoop cluster running Cloudera's `CDH3`, Apache Hadoop's `0.20.2` equivalent. I want to restart the job-tracker as there are some jobs which are not getting killed. I tried killing them from the command line, the command executes successfully, but the jobs are still in `Job Cleanup: Pending` status. Anyways I want to `restart` the `job-tracker` and see if that cleanup the jobs. I know the command to restart the job-tracker, but I am not sure if I need to put the `name-node in safe-mode before I restart the job-tracker`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to kill the unwanted jobs using `hadoop job -kill <Job-ID>` and check for command status `echo "$?"`. If that doesn't work, Restart is the only option.

Hadoop Jobtracker and namenodes are independent components, No need to execute namenode safenode before Jobtracker restart. You can restart Jobtracker process alone.(tasktracker if required)